# Navigation controller bar is low for no reason

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I created a Tab Bar Controller, with 4 navigation controllers each containing one view controller, but on these view controllers, the bar titles are super low. It doesn't matter if I choose large title or not, the issue is the same with regular titles.
Is it because of the tab bar?

[image: f]

[image: largetitles]

[image: smalltitles]

Does someone knows how to fix it? When I set a custom frame for the navigation bar it doesn't have any influence.
And when I push a new view controller, we can't interact with anything that's in the first 25% of the screen (probably because it's behind the navigation bar title, even when i set it to none). That's really weird, how do I set the titles higher or just disable them?

This is also what's in my scene delegate :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! UIViewController
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: storyboard)
window?.rootViewController = navigation
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The view controller with Identifier 'Main' is actually to tab bar at the top of the storyboard, so maybe there's an issue with my scene delegate, but I don't know why this could have an influence on the position of the navigation bar.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code.

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't even use code yet, all I did was set the view and navigation controllers in the storybard. You mean the code about the navigation bar frame ?

Comment: Are you creating the hierarchy as `Root` -> `TabBarController` -> `NavigationController`? Or is it `Root` -> `NavigationController` -> `TabBarController`?

Comment: @Fogmeister I updated the picture so you can see, I don't really know

Comment: @JOHNY thanks, it looks like you are doing it correctly. Hmm... it's really odd. Would you be able to share the project on GitHub? I'd be able to have a quick look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code from your question:

```
// instantiate the UITabBarController with identifier "Main"
//  from Storyboard named "TabBar"
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! UIViewController

// create a new UINavigationController, with the 
//  instantiated UITabBarController as its Root View Controller
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: storyboard)

// show the navigation controller
window?.rootViewController = navigation
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

So, you have:

- a Navigation Controller (with its own navigation bar)
- holding a Tab Bar Controller
- each tab has ***its own navigation controller and navigation bar***

Change your code to this (although it is very confusing object naming):

```
// instantiate the UITabBarController with identifier "Main"
//  from Storyboard named "TabBar"
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! UIViewController

// show the tab bar controller
window?.rootViewController = storyboard
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

That said... why are you not setting that directly in your project setup? Why do this loading from code?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you for your answer. I'm doing it in scene delegate because I have a Firebase auth condition to present the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check if you have selected Prefers Large Titles (If then uncheck it).

Comment: The issue is the same. The title is still really low

Comment: Please share your navigationBar Attribute Inspector screenshot.